# Qt - CDB crashes after setting PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, qt, boost-python, cdb

I am embedding python with boost::python. Everything works fine until I set PYTHONPATH environment variable - then debugger crashes with message

> The CDB process terminated

Debugger output

> ERROR: Process crashed dCDB PROCESS FINISHED, status 1, exit code
>   -1073740791 dNOTE: ENGINE ILL ****** dState changed from EngineSetupRequested(1) to EngineShutdownRequested(19) [master] dCALL:
>   SHUTDOWN ENGINE dNOTE: ENGINE SHUTDOWN OK dState changed from
>   EngineShutdownRequested(19) to EngineShutdownOk(21) [master] dState
>   changed from EngineShutdownOk(21) to DebuggerFinished(22) [master]
>   sDebugger finished.

Qt Creator

> Qt Creator 4.5.1 Based on Qt 5.10.1 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit)
>
> Built on Feb 10 2018 04:20:12
>
> From revision 24cd0b1cd6

Qt

> 5.10.0

Python

> Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500
>   64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

VC

> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.12.25835 for x64

PYTHONHOME variable is set and not causing any issues at all.

Answer (score 0):

**WORKAROUND:** Switched from Qt Creator 4.5.1 to 4.2.2

> Qt Creator 4.2.2 Based on Qt 5.8.0 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit)
>
> Built on Apr 3 2017 04:13:59
>
> From revision 991f5eb6a5

https://forum.qt.io/topic/69130/unexpected-cdb-exit/12
@Christoph Schaefer